# How to clear the screen and how to run the code after the levelOne loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x, pygame

Full code and files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gqke6hfooz7mbnr/Qm8NMlyNqc

Can't seem to find the an solution to this dilemma. Basicly I press space to go to the next loop (`levelTwo`) and it just stops, nothing new appears on the screen even though I have code to do that. I'd really appreciate the help.

Part of the code with probably the dilemma but not sure:

```
    if len(rabbits) == 0:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        windowSurface.blit (textLevelOne, (100, 104))
        levelOne = False
        windowSurface.fill((0,0,0))

    #Ritar fönstret
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)

#LEVEL TWO ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    startSoundLevelTwo = True
while levelOne == False:
    levelTwo = True
    if startSoundLevelTwo == True:
        rabbitSound.play()
        foxSound.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        startSoundLevelTwo = False
        pigSpawn = True
        boarSpawn = True
```

Comment: Your code link won't load for me.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gqke6hfooz7mbnr/Qm8NMlyNqc)
Heres the link. @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level 2 lacks the `pygame.display.update()` call.

Personally, I like to structure pygame code with one main loop, like this:

```
level = 1
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # Process event, update game state:
        if level == 1:
            # Update level 1 state
        elif level == 2:
            # Update level 1 state

    # Clear screen:
    windowSurface.fill((0,0,0))

    # Draw current state to screen:
    if level == 1:
        # Play level 2 music
        # Draw level 1 state to screen

    elif level == 2:
        # Play level 2 music
        # Draw level 2 state to screen
    ...

    # Update screen and control FPS
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

You can use functions for each level, so you keep the main loop simple.

Comment: I was actually now gonna try to convert my code into object oriented coding, if that's possible even. Got any good tutorials somewhere for PyGame, Python and OOC(Object Oriented Coding)?

Comment: I recommend you to read about sprites: http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html  that should be your first step to object oriented code. You can subclass Sprite to make Rabbits, Pigs, etc; as shown in this tutorial: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/category/programming/python/pygame-tutorial/

Comment: This is bad practice, how would the code look if there where 5 levels? How about 10?

Comment: Instead of pointing the problem out, use constructive critisism and propose fixes etc.

Comment: @bartlomiej lewandowski the if-elif isn't what i'm trying to point out, but the good pygame practice of keeping a clean main loop which is a general problem in the posted/linked code (if you looked at it).